# How to configure Tomcat server 8 in Intelij Idea 14?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I am trying to write my first web application and I didn't find configurations for Tomcat server.

[image]

Already installed Tomcat 8 and it works fine, when I launch it from command line.
Manager App runs without problem too.

I know that I can try to deploy from manager, but I want try to used it from Idea.

Where I can find how to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! Problem solved by configuration plugins.